# My neural network has learned to ignore its input and always give the same answer. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a neural network in Python which is mostly from scratch to check my understanding of how they work. The task I've given it is to reverse an 8-term list of ones and zeros, e.g. "[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]" as input should result in "[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]" as output.

However, after the training process it always gives the same prediction regardless of which input I give it, which is obviously not ideal. I'm new to this so I'm probably doing something obviously silly but I don't know what. Where does this go wrong? Here's my code:

```
#imports
import random as r
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm


#State Constants
nNeurons = 8 #Number of neurons per layer
nLayers = 24 #Number of layers
nWeights = nNeurons + 1
trainingDataSize = 10000 #Training data size
nIterations = 250 #Number of iterations of each algorithm
testSize = 100 #Number of data points used for a loss function for the whole network
nAttempts = 5 #Number of models gradient descent back propegation generates

#Data

#Objective function
def f(x):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        output.append(x[-i-1])
    return(output)

#Random 8-bit binary vector
def randomX():
    output = []
    for i in range(8):
        output.append(r.choice([0,1]))
    return(output)

#Generating the training data
trainingData = []
for i in range(trainingDataSize):
    x = randomX()
    trainingData.append([x, f(x)])

#Functions
def sigmoid(x):
    if x < -10:
        return(0)
    else:
        return(1/(1 + np.e**(-x)))

def neuron(w, x):
    output = w[0]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        output += w[i + 1] * x[i]
    activation = tanh(output)
    return(sigmoid(activation))

def generateWeights():
    return(100 * (np.random.rand(nLayers, nNeurons, nWeights) - 0.5))

def hiddenLayer(layerNum, inp, hiddenWeights):
    w = hiddenWeights[layerNum]
    output = []
    for i in range(nNeurons):
        output.append(neuron(w[i],inp))
    return(output)

def neuralNetwork(inp, weights):
    lay = inp
    for i in range(nLayers):
        lay = hiddenLayer(i, lay, weights)
    return(lay)

#Loss of a single data point based on the current weights
def lossOne(weights):
    dataPoint = r.choice(trainingData)
    output = 0
    prediction = neuralNetwork(dataPoint[0], weights)
    actual = dataPoint[1]
    for i in range(len(prediction)):
        output += 0.5 * (prediction[i] - actual[i]) ** 2
    return(output)

#Loss of several data points
def loss(weights):
    output = 0
    for i in range(testSize):
        output += lossOne(weights)
    return(output)

def hiddenLayer(layerNum, inp, hiddenWeights):
w = hiddenWeights[layerNum]
output = []
for i in range(nNeurons):
    output.append(neuron(w[i],inp))
return(output)

def layerLoss(layerNum, inp, weights, expectedOut):
    output = 0
    actualOut = hiddenLayer(layerNum, inp, weights)
    for i in range(len(expectedOut)):
        output += 0.5 * (actualOut[i] - expectedOut[i]) ** 2
    return(output)

scale = 100
dw = 0.01
bestY = 10 ** 10 #For tracking which weight is best
for h in tqdm(range(nAttempts)):
    currentW = generateWeights()

    #Using back-propegation to train the network with gradient descent
    for i in tqdm(range(nIterations)):

        dataPoint = r.choice(trainingData)
        lay = dataPoint[0]
        expectedOut = dataPoint[1]

        for j in range(nLayers):

            for k in range(nNeurons):

                #Gradient descent on the kth neuron in layer - j - 1
                for l in range(j): #Finding the input this layer recieives
                    lay = hiddenLayer(l, lay, currentW)
            
                currentY = layerLoss(-j - 1, lay, currentW, expectedOut)

                nearbyW = currentW
                nearbyW[-j - 1][k] += dw
                nearbyY = layerLoss(-j - 1, lay, nearbyW, expectedOut)

                dY = nearbyY - currentY
                pert = r.uniform(-dw ** 2,dw ** 2) #Small perturbation to prevent getting stuck at maxima

                currentW[-j - 1][k] -= (scale * dY/dw) + pert


            expectedOut = lay
        
        
    #Keeping the best model
    newY = loss(currentW)
    if newY < bestY:
        bestW = currentW
        bestY = newY

#Testing the neural network
tstx = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
tstGD = neuralNetwork(tstx, bestW)
```

I noticed that it usually predicts "0.2689..." and "0.7310..." as the probabilities, which is weird because it seems unlikely to be equally sure of each prediction. Can anyone explain what I got wrong here to cause it to always predict the same value regardless of the input and to always be either 26% sure or 73% sure?

Comment: What does the system output when you give it `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`? It has to output a vector of 8 numbers, can you post the result you are getting? Also 24 hidden layers seem excessive. Reversing an array can be achieved just connecting the input layer to the output layer with no hidden layers at all, so having a few for robustness should be enough

Comment: Thanks! It gives a different output each time I retrain, but currently it is telling me "[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]"

Comment: I reduced nLayers to 5 and increased nAttempts to 25 and it still just picks a random vector and always gives that vector (this time it's "[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]")

Comment: you need a metric on how good it performs. Disable the threshold in the last layer so you get your output as floating point numbers, then you can compute the overall error of the system. eg: if you expect [0, 1] and you get [0.4, 0.8] the error is [0.4-0, 1-0.8] = [0.4, 0.2] -> 0.6. Initially you should get random answers, so an average error of 0.5 for each output. Keep track of the error at each train iteration and check that it gets down so it means that the system is learning. Check that it doesn't oscillate and at some point it should stop decreasing.

Comment: After this feed the system with your test set and check that it gives similar performance. If not it might mean that your system is overfitting and your training set is not general enough. 25 attempts seems a bit low to me, neural networks sometimes need a lot of iterations to get proper results. The important thing that you have to do is to ensure that your system is learning by seeing how the overall error decreases at each training step